# How do I add video content to the gapi youtube insert api

Tags: javascript, http, youtube-api, blob, google-api-js-client

I have a react application which is currently authenticating a gapi client. I have checked this functionality by calling the api to get channels using the client with 'gapi.client.youtube.channels.list' and everything seems to be working fine

I also have an axios request which is calling a local mp4 file and returning the raw data from the file. This again seems to be working correctly and saving raw data to a variable

Now when I try to call the upload api I am getting an error which states..
"The request does not include the video content" with a 400 code.

My upload code can be seen below. The raw video data is saved to the variable "rawVideoData"

```
//get the file data
Axios.get('http://myURL/video.mp4')
.then((res) =>{
  let rawVideoData = new Blob([res.data], {type:'video/mp4'})

  //run the upload code here...
}
.catch((e) =>{
  console.log(e)
})

//this is the upload code (would be running inside the Axios.then)
try{
    let req = gapi.client.youtube.videos.insert({
      part:'id,snippet,status',
      notifySubscribers:false,
      mimeType:'video/mp4',
      requestBody:{
        snippet:{
          title:"test video",
          description:"this is a test video"
        },
        status:{
          privacyStatus:'unlisted'
        }
      },
      media:{
        body:rawVideoData
      }
    })
    req.execute((response) =>{
      console.log(response)
    })
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e)
  }
```

I'm struggling to find any docs which suggest how to structure this part of the request.
I have also tried the following setups

```
    let req = window.gapi.client.youtube.videos.insert({
      part:'id,snippet,status',
      notifySubscribers:false,
      mimeType:'video/mp4'
      requestBody:{
        snippet:{
          title:"test video 5",
          description:"this is a test video"
        },
        status:{
          privacyStatus:'unlisted'
        },
        media:{
          body:rawVideoData
        }
      }
    })


    let req = window.gapi.client.youtube.videos.insert({
      part:'id,snippet,status',
      notifySubscribers:false,
      mimeType:'video/mp4'
      requestBody:{
        snippet:{
          title:"test video 5",
          description:"this is a test video"
        },
        status:{
          privacyStatus:'unlisted'
        },
        body:rawVideoData
      }
    })


    let req = window.gapi.client.youtube.videos.insert({
      part:'id,snippet,status',
      notifySubscribers:false,
      mimeType:'video/mp4'
      requestBody:{
        snippet:{
          title:"test video 5",
          description:"this is a test video"
        },
        status:{
          privacyStatus:'unlisted'
        }
      },
      body:rawVideoData
    })
```

All of the above produce the same error. 
Does anybody know how I need to attach the video data to the request?

Comment: make sure body:rawVideoData is a file stream also i think you need to add the mime type.

Comment: Right okay I've now taken the raw data and used it to create a blob of type 'video/mp4'. For the mime type do I just add 'mime:video/*' to the request?

Comment: i think its  mimeType: 'video/mp4',  but you might want to check the documentation.  I havent done this with the javascript library personally.

Comment: I seem to be getting the same error so far. I'll add my file/blob code into the question in case i'm doing something wrong there